# Node/Puppeteer/ChromeDevTools: Shell says variable's property undefined even though defined! Why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, code-coverage

trying to use puppeteer/node to extract only the used CSS and JS into separate .css and .js files but powershell keeps returning the following error and I cannot seem to figure out why it's doing this as the variable should clearly have a length since the script should have fed some data to it. Perhaps one of the processes preceding it is causing this? I'm not sure what the problem is.

The shell returns:

```
       css_total_bytes += entry.text.length;
                                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
//Include to be able to export files w/ node
const fs = require('fs');
const iPhone = puppeteer.devices['iPhone 6'];

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.emulate(iPhone);

    //Begin collecting CSS coverage data
    await Promise.all([
        page.coverage.startCSSCoverage(),
        page.coverage.startJSCoverage()
    ]);

    //Visit desired page
    await page.goto('http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html');
  
    //Stop collection and retrieve the coverage iterator
    const [cssCoverage, jsCoverage] = await Promise.all([
        page.coverage.stopCSSCoverage(),
        page.coverage.stopJSCoverage()
    ]);

    //Investigate CSS Coverage and Extract Used CSS
    var css_coverage = [...cssCoverage];
    var css_used_bytes = 0;
    var css_total_bytes = 0;
    var covered_css = "";
    for (var entry in css_coverage[0]) {
        css_total_bytes += entry.text.length;
        console.log(`Total Bytes for ${entry.url}: ${entry.text.length}`);
        for (var range in entry.ranges){
            css_used_bytes += range.end - range.start - 1;
            covered_css += entry.text.slice(range.start, range.end) + "\n";
        }       
    }

    //Investigate JS Coverage and Extract Used JS
    var js_coverage = [...jsCoverage];
    var js_used_bytes = 0;
    var js_total_bytes = 0;
    var js_css = "";
    for (var entry in js_coverage[0]) {
        js_total_bytes += entry.text.length;
        console.log(`Total Bytes for ${entry.url}: ${entry.text.length}`);
        for (var range in entry.ranges){
            js_used_bytes += range.end - range.start - 1;
            js_css += entry.text.slice(range.start, range.end) + "\n";
        }       
    }

    console.log(`Total Bytes of CSS: ${css_total_bytes}`);
    console.log(`Used Bytes of CSS: ${css_used_bytes}`);
    fs.writeFile("./exported_css.css", covered_css, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("The CSS file was saved!");
    }); 

    console.log(`Total Bytes of JS: ${js_total_bytes}`);
    console.log(`Used Bytes of JS: ${js_used_bytes}`);
    fs.writeFile("./exported_js.js", covered_js, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("The JS file was saved!");
    });

    await browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand [the docs](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#class-coverage) correctly, these are some issues:

1. `var css_coverage = [...cssCoverage];` — this seems redundant as `cssCoverage` is already an array.
2. `for (var entry in css_coverage[0]) {`:

   - `css_coverage[0]` is a coverage entry, you need not iterate over its content.
   - `for ... in` loop iterates over object properties, you need `for ... of` loop to iterate over array entries (the same for ranges iteration).

So try something like this (the same for JS coverage):

```js
    //Investigate CSS Coverage and Extract Used CSS
    var css_used_bytes = 0;
    var css_total_bytes = 0;
    var covered_css = "";
    for (var entry of cssCoverage) {
        css_total_bytes += entry.text.length;
        console.log(`Total Bytes for ${entry.url}: ${entry.text.length}`);
        for (var range of entry.ranges){
            css_used_bytes += range.end - range.start - 1;
            covered_css += entry.text.slice(range.start, range.end) + "\n";
        }
    }
```